# Do we say zero point or zero points?

Tags: grammatical-number

I know we say one point or two points, how about zero?
Do you say zero **point** or zero **points**?
Or both are ok depending on the context?

Comment: I would say "no points".

Comment: Presumably the context doesn't involve zero-point energy, "zero points" would work for most other circumstances I'd have thought.

Answer (score 1):

In any context where plural is possible, I would use "points". For example, "they found zero points where the curves intersected."

If only a singular would be used, use "point". For example, "there is zero point to continuing this conversation."

Comment: I'm with @nnnnnn above. I would also say "no points" or "no point in continuing this conversation". I might, however, use "zero point" to  refer to a point on a graph where the plot intersected with either or both axes as it intersects the x axis where y equals 0 and vice versa.